# $_POST not picking up value (getJSON)

Tags: php, jquery, json, post, getjson

I am trying to use getJSON to pull data from a PHP file however when I pass in "data" it the $_POST call doesn't seem to be retrieving any data.

```
function runJSON(network,searchType){
        var URL     = returnURL(network,searchType,$('#song_field').val().split(' ').join("+"));

    var val = $('#song_field').val();
    var data = {val: val}

    $.getJSON(URL, val, function(data){
        if(document.getElementById("box") !== "undefined"){
            clearScreen();
            createCols();
        }

        songList = [];
        console.log(data);
        eval(network + "(data);");

        for(i = 0; i < songList.length; i++)
        {   
            displayTrack(i);
        }

        done = true; 

    });
}
```

php file:

```
<?php
    $input = $_POST["val"];
    $url   = "http://api.7digital.com/1.2/track/search?q=" . $input . "&oauth_consumer_key=myconsumerkey&country=GB&pagesize=2";

    $data = simplexml_load_file($url);
    $json = json_encode($data);
    echo ($json);
?>
```

Comment: can you verify that $data contains what you expect it to in your php code?

Comment: can you add the json generated by the php file?

Comment: `getJSON()` sends a GET request, always. `$_POST` only includes values from POST requests. You want `$_GET`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your `$.getJSON` call should pass in `data` not `val`:

```
$.getJSON(URL, val, function(data){
```

should be

```
$.getJSON(URL, data, function(data){
```

And your php should use `$_GET` not `$_POST`

```
$input = $_POST["val"];
```

should be

```
$input = $_GET["val"];
```

Comment: This is the sort of thing I expected but I really had no idea how getJSON worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You are using `getJSON` in wrong way,

```
var val = $('#song_field').val();

$.getJSON(URL, {val: val}, function(data){ //<- Note how data passed
```

Also, `getJSON` uses `GET` method so in PHP, use `$_GET` or `$_REQUEST`, i.e.

```
$_REQUEST['val']
```

or

```
$_GET['val']
```

**Documentation:** http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/